# Should we have a new, improved matrix determinant challenge?

Tags: discussion, policy, challenge-quality

There is currently [a challenge to compute the determinant of a matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8405/45941). However, it was written 5 years ago, before our current quality standards were established. It falls short of those standards in several ways:

- Inflexible I/O (must be STDIN and STDOUT)
- Cumbersome I/O format (whitespace-separated input)
- Underspecified (the ring in which the matrix elements belong is unspecified -
  many answers make assumptions)

Most of the 8 answers are quite old. All but 2 are from 2012, shortly after the challenge was posed.

Does this challenge deserve a rewrite?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Yes, it does

As I noted in the question, the challenge has several flaws that make it a poor fit for the current state of the site. Rather than making large edits to the challenge and potentially invalidating old answers (as well as making them uncompetitive), it would be much better to write a new version of the challenge that is up to modern quality standards, and close the old challenge as a dupe of the new one.

Comment: Keep in mind that many languages will have builtins, so I hope voters will look for well golfed answers instead of just short ones. That's another discussion though.